# How to create an ObservableBooleanValue from a boolean value

Tags: java, javafx, boolean

Given I have a javafx input field with a validator on it (example taken from the JFoenix [library](http://www.jfoenix.com/documentation.html#InputFields)):

```
JFXTextField validationField = new JFXTextField();
validationField.setPromptText("Your age");

NumberValidator validator = new NumberValidator();
validator.setMessage("Digits only!");    
validationField.getValidators().add(validator);
validationField.focusedProperty().addListener((o,oldVal,newVal)->{
    if(!newVal) validationField.validate();
});
```

My goal is to enable/disable some button only if the validation on the text field returns true, however `validationField.validate()` returns a boolean instead of a ObservableBooleanValue.

```
BooleanBinding invalid = someOtherTextField.textProperty().isEmpty()
                .or(!validationField.validate()); // invalid syntax                                 
candidateButton.disableProperty().bind(invalid);
```

How do I create an ObservableBooleanValue from a validation of a text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `BooleanBinding` using the [`Bindings.createBooleanBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createBooleanBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-) method. You need to specify a `Callable<Boolean>` (a function that returns the value to be wrapped in the `BooleanBinding`), along with any other `Observable`s that must be observed so that the function is recomputed when they change.

So you can do

```
BooleanBinding invalid = someOtherTextField.textProperty().isEmpty()
    .or(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> !validationField.validate(), 
        validationField.textProperty()));
```

I don't know JFoenix (I've looked at it a few times, but there doesn't seem to be any reasonable documentation for the library - e.g. there are no Javadocs - so as far as I am concerned it is not really usable in production). There might be a way to get a binding directly.